# Maas custom config for ubuntu

Tags: maas

Now, I have this problem with Maas:

I've made custom configuration for my Ubuntu 16.04 install (as different partitioning and drive configuration needed in my case). Our servers has several hard drives with two of them dedicated for system (usually smallest two). So I've created custom config for such configuration, which uses some scripts to determine smallest two drives. After that we use custom partitioning, including software raids creation. So far everything works, but in some cases installation fails on grub-install. Question is: I need to change grub config in curtin, so it could get correct devices for grub-install or disable grub section completely. My custom_userdata_ubuntu right now looks like this:

```
#cloud-config
debconf_selections:
 maas: |
  {{for line in str(curtin_preseed).splitlines()}}
  {{line}}
  {{endfor}}

early_commands:
  01_get_device_list_script: wget -O /bin/list-devices http://10.7.36.1/list-devices
  02_get_smallest_drives_script: wget -O /tmp/root_disk.sh http://10.7.36.1/root_disk.sh
  03_chmod_list_devices: chmod 755 /bin/list-devices
  04_set_drive_1: /bin/bash /tmp/root_disk.sh raid1_2_disk1 >/tmp/drive1
  05_set_drive_2: /bin/bash /tmp/root_disk.sh raid1_2_disk2 >/tmp/drive2

partitioning_commands:
  builtin: []
  01_apt_get_update: apt-get update
  02_install_gdisk: apt-get -y install gdisk mdadm kpartx
  02_stop_raid_devices: for i in `ls /dev | grep -P 'md[0-9+]'`; do mdadm --stop /dev/$i; done
  02_wait_for_device_to_settle: sleep 10; echo "Devices should be settled"
  03_erase_metadata_drive_1: for i in 2 3 4 5 6 7; do mdadm --zero-superblock $(cat /tmp/drive1)${i} || /bin/true; done
  03_erase_metadata_drive_2: for i in 2 3 4 5 6 7; do mdadm --zero-superblock $(cat /tmp/drive2)${i} || /bin/true; done
  04_start_partitioning: echo Starting partitioning; sleep 10
  05_set_drive1_label: /sbin/parted $(cat /tmp/drive1) -s mklabel gpt
  06_set_drive2_label: /sbin/parted $(cat /tmp/drive2) -s mklabel gpt
  07_set_boot_part_1: /sbin/parted -s $(cat /tmp/drive1) unit s mkpart biosboot 2048 4095
  08_set_bios_boot_1: /sbin/parted -s $(cat /tmp/drive1) set 1 bios_grub on
  09_mk_swap_1: /sbin/parted -s $(cat /tmp/drive1)  mkpart primary 2098K 32G
  10_parted_mk_root_1: /sbin/parted -s $(cat /tmp/drive1) mkpart primary ext4 32G 52G
  11_parted_: /sbin/parted -s $(cat /tmp/drive1) mkpart primary ext4 52G 72G
  12_parted_: /sbin/parted -s $(cat /tmp/drive1) mkpart primary ext4 72G 92G
  13_parted_: /sbin/parted -s $(cat /tmp/drive1) mkpart primary ext4 92G 112G
  14_parted_: /sbin/parted -s $(cat /tmp/drive1) mkpart primary ext4 112G 100%
  141_start_copy_partitioning: echo Starting Partitioning copy process
  15_sgdisk_copy_table: /sbin/sgdisk -R $(cat /tmp/drive2) $(cat /tmp/drive1)
  16_sgdisk_generate_uuid: /sbin/sgdisk -G $(cat /tmp/drive2)
  17_parted_set_raid_1_2: /sbin/parted $(cat /tmp/drive1) set 2 "raid" on
  18_parted_set_raid_1_3: /sbin/parted $(cat /tmp/drive1) set 3 "raid" on
  19_parted_set_raid_1_4: /sbin/parted $(cat /tmp/drive1) set 4 "raid" on
  20_parted_set_raid_1_5: /sbin/parted $(cat /tmp/drive1) set 5 "raid" on
  21_parted_set_raid_1_6: /sbin/parted $(cat /tmp/drive1) set 6 "raid" on
  22_parted_set_raid_1_7: /sbin/parted $(cat /tmp/drive1) set 7 "raid" on
  23_parted_set_raid_2_2: /sbin/parted $(cat /tmp/drive2) set 2 "raid" on
  24_parted_set_raid_2_3: /sbin/parted $(cat /tmp/drive2) set 3 "raid" on
  25_parted_set_raid_2_4: /sbin/parted $(cat /tmp/drive2) set 4 "raid" on
  26_parted_set_raid_2_5: /sbin/parted $(cat /tmp/drive2) set 5 "raid" on
  27_parted_set_raid_2_6: /sbin/parted $(cat /tmp/drive2) set 6 "raid" on
  28_parted_set_raid_2_7: /sbin/parted $(cat /tmp/drive2) set 7 "raid" on
  28_let_devices_settle: sleep 10; echo "and again devices should be settled"
  29_mdadm_create_swap: yes | mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --force --raid-disks=2 --metadata=0.90 $(cat /tmp/drive2)2 $(cat /tmp/drive1)2
  30_mdadm_create_root: yes | mdadm --create /dev/md1 --level=1 --force --raid-disks=2 --metadata=0.90 $(cat /tmp/drive2)3 $(cat /tmp/drive1)3
  31_mdadm_create_usr:  yes | mdadm --create /dev/md2 --level=1 --force --raid-disks=2 --metadata=0.90 $(cat /tmp/drive2)4 $(cat /tmp/drive1)4
  32_mdadm_create_var:  yes | mdadm --create /dev/md3 --level=1 --force --raid-disks=2 --metadata=0.90 $(cat /tmp/drive2)5 $(cat /tmp/drive1)5
  33_mdadm_create_home: yes | mdadm --create /dev/md4 --level=1 --force --raid-disks=2 --metadata=0.90 $(cat /tmp/drive2)6 $(cat /tmp/drive1)6
  34_mdadm_create_data: yes | mdadm --create /dev/md5 --level=1 --force --raid-disks=2 --metadata=0.90 $(cat /tmp/drive2)7 $(cat /tmp/drive1)7
  35_mkswap: mkswap /dev/md0
  36_mkfs_root: mkfs -t ext4 /dev/md1
  37_mkfs_usr:  mkfs -t ext4 /dev/md2
  38_mkfs_var:  mkfs -t ext4 /dev/md3
  39_mkfs_home: mkfs -t ext4 /dev/md4
  40_mkfs_data: mkfs -t ext4 /dev/md5
  41_mount_root: mount /dev/md1 ${TARGET_MOUNT_POINT}
  42_mkdirs: mkdir ${TARGET_MOUNT_POINT}/usr ${TARGET_MOUNT_POINT}/var ${TARGET_MOUNT_POINT}/home ${TARGET_MOUNT_POINT}/data; mkdir -p ${TARGET_MOUNT_POINT}/boot/grub
  43_mount_usr: mount /dev/md2 ${TARGET_MOUNT_POINT}/usr
  44_mount_var: mount /dev/md3 ${TARGET_MOUNT_POINT}/var
  45_mount_home: mount /dev/md4 ${TARGET_MOUNT_POINT}/home
  46_mount_data: mount /dev/md5 ${TARGET_MOUNT_POINT}/data
  47_fstab_root: echo "/dev/md1 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1" >> $OUTPUT_FSTAB
  48_fstab_usr:  echo "/dev/md2 /usr ext4 defaults 0 2" >> $OUTPUT_FSTAB
  49_fstab_var:  echo "/dev/md3 /var ext4 defaults 0 1" >> $OUTPUT_FSTAB
  50_fstab_home: echo "/dev/md4 /home ext4 defaults 0 2" >> $OUTPUT_FSTAB
  51_fstab_data: echo "/dev/md5 /data ext4 defaults 0 2" >> $OUTPUT_FSTAB
  52_fstab_swap: echo "/dev/md0 none swap sw 0 0" >> $OUTPUT_FSTAB
  53_make_device_map_dir: for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5; do echo "(md/$i)       /dev/md$i)" >>${TARGET_MOUNT_POINT}/boot/grub/device.map; done

swap:
  filename: swap.img
  size: 0

late_commands:
  maas: [wget, '--no-proxy', '{{node_disable_pxe_url}}', '--post-data', '{{node_disable_pxe_data}}', '-O', '/dev/null']
  40_create_grub_config: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg"]
  41_install_bootloader_drive_1: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "grub-install $(cat /tmp/drive1)"]
  42_install_bootloader_drive_1: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "grub-install $(cat /tmp/drive2)"]
  51_fill_mdadm: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "mdadm --examine --scan >/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf"]
  52_update_initramfs: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "update-initramfs -u -k all"]
```

The problem is that in some cases where we have two system HDD's and also we have JBOD enabled on raid controller installation fails, cause grub trying to install itself on /dev/sda, which in that case may not be system disk, but jbod disk that kernel set as sda and it's empty. Is there any way to tell maas to install grub on another disk from within (or disable install grub as I have it in late section of config)?

Also there's another questions about maas behavior after install, which are:

1. When releasing server Maas powers it off - how do I disable such behavior?
2. Also after release Maas doesn't change boot device from PXE, so first boot after that fails cause PXE configuration no longer exists.
3. After successful deploy of server Maas doesn't show server ip address in interfaces section, how do we fix that?

Comment: I've edited my maas installation and disabled network boot after release (also disabled poweroff too). I think that I'll make it optional (like secure erase and such) in interface and send Maas authors patch for this after it will be done. Still question about IP address exists (although it's not that important, as we can assign static ip before deployment).

Answer (score 1):

Now, I've been looking through Maas code and online references, so I've created new configuration, maybe someone will like it.
What works:
1. Detecting smallest drives, if we have two drives with same size then we creating software raids with mount points for /, /usr, /var, /home 
2. Grub correctly installing itself when device is not sda/sdb.

What doesn't work as intended is resolv.conf config, I think it's either dnsmasq or something like that, which ignores my network config and puts 127.0.0.1 in resolv.conf, will look into it though. Also  chould be changed to something like example.org
Also I've added late commands from my config in this listing (though I've omited some of them), which adds facts for puppet, install puppet-agent and runs it (after puppet run there's also killall section - it needed to free chroot environment, as it fails install otherwise, cause temporary dir stays busy and couldn't be unmounted)

```
#cloud-config
debconf_selections:
 maas: |
  {{for line in str(curtin_preseed).splitlines()}}
  {{line}}
  {{endfor}}


early_commands:
  01_empty_command: echo INSTALLATION STARTED
{{py:
import operator
deviceListTmp = node.blockdevice_set.all()
deviceList = sorted(deviceListTmp, key=operator.attrgetter('size'))
has_raid = False
if (len(deviceList) > 1):
   bootdrive_1 = deviceList[0]
   bootdrive_2 = deviceList[1]
   if bootdrive_1.size == bootdrive_2.size:
      has_raid = True
else:
   bootdrive_1 = deviceList[0]
}}

{{if has_raid}}
storage:
  version: 1
  config:
    - id: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}
      type: disk
      ptable: gpt
      path: /dev/{{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}
      name: boot_drive_1
      grub_device: 1
      wipe: superblock-recursive
    - id: bios_boot_partition_1
      type: partition
      size: 1MB
      device: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}
      flag: bios_grub
    - id: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}2
      type: partition
      size: 30G
      device: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}
    - id: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}3
      type: partition
      size: 19G
      device: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}
    - id: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}4
      type: partition
      size: 19G
      device: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}
    - id: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}5
      type: partition
      size: 19G
      device: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}
    - id: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}6
      type: partition
      size: 19G
      device: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}
    - id: {{bootdrive_2.name.strip()}}
      type: disk
      ptable: gpt
      path: /dev/{{bootdrive_2.name.strip()}}
      name: boot_drive_2
      grub_device: 1
      wipe: superblock-recursive
    - id: bios_boot_partition_2
      type: partition
      size: 1MB
      device: {{bootdrive_2.name.strip()}}
      flag: bios_grub
    - id: {{bootdrive_2.name.strip()}}2
      type: partition
      size: 30G
      device: {{bootdrive_2.name.strip()}}
    - id: {{bootdrive_2.name.strip()}}3
      type: partition
      size: 19G
      device: {{bootdrive_2.name.strip()}}
    - id: {{bootdrive_2.name.strip()}}4
      type: partition
      size: 19G
      device: {{bootdrive_2.name.strip()}}
    - id: {{bootdrive_2.name.strip()}}5
      type: partition
      size: 19G
      device: {{bootdrive_2.name.strip()}}
    - id: {{bootdrive_2.name.strip()}}6
      type: partition
      size: 19G
      device: {{bootdrive_2.name.strip()}}
    - id: mddevice0
      name: md0
      type: raid
      raidlevel: 1
      devices:
        - {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}2
        - {{bootdrive_2.name.strip()}}2
    - id: mddevice1
      name: md1
      type: raid
      raidlevel: 1
      devices:
        - {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}3
        - {{bootdrive_2.name.strip()}}3
    - id: mddevice2
      name: md2
      type: raid
      raidlevel: 1
      devices:
        - {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}4
        - {{bootdrive_2.name.strip()}}4
    - id: mddevice3
      name: md3
      type: raid
      raidlevel: 1
      devices:
        - {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}5
        - {{bootdrive_2.name.strip()}}5
    - id: mddevice4
      name: md4
      type: raid
      raidlevel: 1
      devices:
        - {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}6
        - {{bootdrive_2.name.strip()}}6
    - id: md_swap
      type: format
      fstype: swap
      volume: mddevice0
    - id: md_root
      type: format
      fstype: ext4
      volume: mddevice1
    - id: md_usr
      type: format
      fstype: ext4
      volume: mddevice2
    - id: md_var
      type: format
      fstype: ext4
      volume: mddevice3
    - id: md_home
      type: format
      fstype: ext4
      volume: mddevice4
    - id: mount_swap
      type: mount
      device: md_swap
    - id: mount_root
      type: mount
      path: /
      device: md_root
    - id: mount_usr
      type: mount
      path: /usr
      device: md_usr
    - id: mount_var
      type: mount
      path: /var
      device: md_var
    - id: mount_home
      type: mount
      path: /home
      device: md_home

grub:
  install_devices:
    - /dev/{{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}
    - /dev/{{bootdrive_2.name.strip()}}
{{else}}
storage:
  version: 1
  config:
    - id: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}
      type: disk
      ptable: gpt
      path: /dev/{{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}
      name: boot_drive_1
      grub_device: 1
      wipe: superblock-recursive
    - id: bios_boot_partition
      type: partition
      size: 1MB
      device: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}
      flag: bios_grub
    - id: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}2
      type: partition
      size: 30G
      device: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}
    - id: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}3
      type: partition
      size: 19G
      device: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}
    - id: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}4
      type: partition
      size: 19G
      device: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}
    - id: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}5
      type: partition
      size: 19G
      device: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}
    - id: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}6
      type: partition
      size: 19G
      device: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}
    - id: fs_swap
      type: format
      fstype: swap
      volume: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}2
    - id: fs_root
      type: format
      fstype: ext4
      volume: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}3
    - id: fs_usr
      type: format
      fstype: ext4
      volume: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}4
    - id: fs_var
      type: format
      fstype: ext4
      volume: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}5
    - id: fs_home
      type: format
      fstype: ext4
      volume: {{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}6
    - id: mount_swap
      type: mount
      device: fs_swap
    - id: mount_root
      type: mount
      path: /
      device: fs_root
    - id: mount_usr
      type: mount
      path: /usr
      device: fs_usr
    - id: mount_var
      type: mount
      path: /var
      device: fs_var
    - id: mount_home
      type: mount
      path: /home
      device: fs_home

grub:
  install_devices:
    - /dev/{{bootdrive_1.name.strip()}}
{{endif}}

network:
  version: 1
  config:
    - type: nameserver
      address:
        - 10.121.10.1
        - 192.168.121.1
      search:
        - <domainname>


swap:
  filename: swap.img
  size: 0

late_commands:
  12_reconfigure_openssh: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server"]
  13_add_puppet_key: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "wget -O /tmp/puppet.key http://apt.puppetlabs.com/DEB-GPG-KEY-puppet && apt-key add /tmp/puppet.key"]
  14_add_puppet_repo: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "echo 'deb http://apt.puppetlabs.com xenial PC1' >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/puppetlabs-pc1.list && apt-get update"]
  15_run_fix: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "apt-get -y -f install"]
  18_install_puppet_and_requrements: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "apt-get -y install puppet-agent lsof jq ipmiutil wget python-requests parted strace tcpdump mc net-tools lsb-release"]
  20_add_team_fact: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "wget -O /tmp/smdb_data.py http://10.7.36.1/smdb_data.py && python /tmp/smdb_data.py && rm -f /tmp/smdb_data.py"]
  21_run_puppet: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "sh", "-c", "/opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet agent -t --server puppet4.<domain>; killall -9 splunkd; killall -9 zabbix_agentd; killall -9 mdadm; lsof /proc"]
  22_display_network_config: cat $OUTPUT_NETWORK_CONFIG
```